Accessing the Model in a IDisplayMetadataProvider using ASP.NET Core
I am using IDisplayMetadataProvider to populate some additionalvalues which I then use for my editor templates.
Is it possible to access the actual Model in the IDisplayMetadataProvider or just the metadata?

It would be nice if you could also share your relevant code snippet what exactly you are trying to achieve. But based on your description, unfortunately, we cannot directly access the actual model instance within an  IDisplayMetadataProvider implementation.  This interface is designed to work with the metadata itself, not the underlying model object. Becuase, IDisplayMetadataProvider focuses on modifying the metadata associated with a property, keeping it separate from the actual model data.

Basically in .NET 4.8 MVC 5 in the context of Editor Templates I could access a model with  ViewContext.Controller.ViewData.Model
This seems to be removed from .NET 8, so I am looking for alternatives.

Well as an alternative you could use of  custom model binder so that you can  access to the actual model instance during the binding process.
